# Can we retrieve Riak Objects instead of keys using 2i

Tags: riak, riak-search

I have a use-case where I need to query based on a 2i value and retrieve all the Riak objects intstead of only keys. Doing a map-reduce operation for this took quite a long time and more computations.

Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Riak does provide the `return_terms` option for 2i queries. So if the data you are interested in was included in the index, you can return that piece directly with the 2i results.

Comment: @Joe return_terms only the index values matched by the range along with the keys in a search query, for more details see the following [link](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/references/http/secondary-indexes/)

Comment: That is true, but I have seen people get creative when they only needed part of the object, like indexing date-email and date-name and date-topic-title in separate indexes so they could return enough with the index query to present to the user for them to select which they wanted to see in full.

Answer (score 0):

Since a 2i search returns a list of matching keys, you can then make multiple parallel requests to fetch the associated objects.

Riak is not like a traditional RDBMS where you try to minimize the number of fetch requests you make. I recommend benchmarking to find an ideal number of parallel requests to maximize performance to fetch objects.

Finally, please ensure that you are using a load balancer between your application and Riak so that these fetch requests are balanced among the nodes in your cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already did benchmark on number of parallel requests but results were not satisfactory when number of keys cross 5K and average riak object size being less than 700KB